# Fitting a peak to subtract baseline

Tags: python

I'm trying to fit a peak to subtract the fitted curve from the data. My aim is to get only the peaks that unfortunately are located on the slope of a background.

[Prominent 50Hz peak with Lorentzian fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5saGX.png)

I tried Gaussian and Lorentzian fits, but nothing comes close to what I intend. Do you know how to get broader shoulders for the Lorentzian fit? Increasing the width raises the error:

*Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800.*

Comment: Lorentzian's have a single parameter for the width.  You may be having trouble because it's normalized, so you might have to allow for the amplitude to vary if you aren't already.  Otherwise it may be that your initial parameters are bad (fixing an amplitude and giving it a good initial width may help), it's not a Lorentzian, there may be too much noise, especially in the tails, that you might want to try narrowing the fit range

Comment: Thank you possum: I tried narrowing the fit range. No results. My goal is to have a flat background with the peaks and without this slope.